# Memcached for php7 and windows 7 for development

Tags: php, windows, memcached

I want to test and study [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) on my localhost, before applying it to production, but I have few problems, [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) is only good with PHP 5.6, the version on the production is PHP 7, so I need to match it so I will not make any errors when I do it in production(atleast).

I searched for a while now how to install [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) that is compatible with PHP 7 and windows 7 os, I don't find the right answer for me. I am a newbie so, please do help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why make life harder on yourself by forcing memcached to work with PHP 7? Just use Redis (or some other cache engine, if you really prefer).

Comment: But, the one that is working on the production is memcached that I mentioned.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really following. If you are able to set it up correctly in production, why aren't you able to do the same in your development environment? Do you have a *nix production environment and Windows development environment? If so, you're going to want to change that. Use a VM or Docker.

Comment: I am using a web hosting, they already have set-up the memcached extension. And yes, I have a windows development environment. Should I search for VM or Docker ?

Comment: Is it like a dual OS in your computer?

Comment: Do you have any link for the additional info about VM or Docker? If yes, please do share it to me. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should google "virtualbox" and "Docker." They're different technologies. Docker is better for many purposes, but I'm not sure whether it's really supported on Windows.